# Npgsql not finding function with XML param, looking for TEXT instead

Tags: .net, postgresql, npgsql

I have a Postgres SQL function called test_xml_func that takes in a parameter of type XML. When calling this function in .NET using Npgsql I get an error saying text_xml_func(text) does not exist. Is there a way to get this to look for the XML function without having to set the NpgsqlParameter's NpgsqlDbType property to XML?

I am using Npgsql v3.0.3 and Postgres 9.5 Beta 1.

Postgres function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_xml_func(_xml XML)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS 
$$
    SELECT TRUE;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

.NET call

```
Using connection As New NpgsqlConnection(ConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("test_xml_func", connection) With {.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure}
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New NpgsqlParameter("_xml", "<ITEMS><ITEM><VALUE>1</VALUE></ITEM></ITEMS>"))
        connection.Open()
        System.Console.WriteLine(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you must set the NpgsqlParameter's NpgsqlDbType to XML. Is there any particular reason you want to avoid this?

When NpgsqlDbType and DbType aren't set on a NpgsqlParameter, Npgsql defaults to type-inferring the PostgreSQL type. In the case of a string value, this is a PostgreSQL text, which is why you're getting an error that text_xml_func(text) isn't defined.

Comment: We are in the process of converting from MSSQL to Postgres and we have a bunch of DB calls that pass XML in as text as shown above. It is going to be a pain to hunt them all down and change them to set NpgsqlDbType to XML so we were hoping there was another way. Looks like our only options are this or to take them in as TEXT and cast to XML before using xpath. Thanks for the response!